# PHP MVC: How would i route controllers through buttons?

Tags: php, html, model-view-controller

I am new to Php mvc design and I have been reading a tutorial, [Simple MVC for beginners](http://requiremind.com/a-most-simple-php-mvc-beginners-tutorial/). In this tutorial the author is routing all calls from the `index.php` file based on some link. I have a landing page written in html and was wondering how would i route my, lets say when a user clicks the sign up button, sign up view based on a button not link?

That brings me to another question. Would a controller even be necessary going from a landing page view to a signup view?

views/layout page:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <a href='/php_mvc_blog'>Home</a>
    </header>

    <?php require_once('routes.php'); ?>

    <footer>
      Copyright
    </footer>
  <body>
<html>
```

index.php:

```
<?php


require_once('connection.php');

  if (isset($_GET['controller']) && isset($_GET['action'])) {
    $controller = $_GET['controller'];
    $action     = $_GET['action'];
  } else {
    $controller = 'pages';
    $action     = 'home';
  }

  require_once('views/layout.php');
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kind of hard to answer as it's not really related to MVC. Hopefully I can give you some insight to point you in the right direction.

MVC is just a concept on how you organise your code. There are many different ways to setup a site which could still be considered MVC.
To put it simply:

- Model: Deals with database logic, one model can be shared by many controllers.
- View: Where your html is (which could include php variables if you
  aren't using js).
- Controller: Where the logic for your php is. e.g. Mapping an array
  for your view, going to a different page etc.

Question 1: Your question isn't exactly dealing with the MCV concept itself and more just how html interacts with php.

1. You have a link or a button with a link in it.
2. This link points to your route which then calls your controller.
3. Your controller runs the php logic you need and then serves the html to the user.

Question 2: If you do not have any php in your html view (like an faq page which doesn't require logic) you can just link directly to the page. However it's probably best to go through a controller which just renders the page to keep it consistent.